# Facebook graph api get posts after a certain post id

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api where I periodically call: https://graph.facebook.com/cnn/posts?access_token=accesstoken

I don't want to get repeat posts the second time I make the call so I would like to filter the call to get anything after either a certain post Id or after a created_time. Is this possible?

I have tried using date_range= but it did not work plus it only allowed me to search by date but not time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use timebased paging: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

The correct parameter would be `since` and `until`. Just store the timestamp of the last post and use it in your next call.